# Android Gradle dependency on a forked GitHub project

Tags: android, github, gradle

I've pulled in a third party custom ListView library into my Android Gradle project. I initially added the project as a gradle library dependency from the jcenter repo. But now I forked the GitHub project and I'm making changes to it.

The original project is no longer maintained, so submitting a pull request is not going to work, I really need my own fork.

What would be a nice way to set this dependency up using Gradle?

I thought of putting the ListView library under the same GitHub repo as my project, but that seems messy, I do want to keep my fork as a separate library.

Another thing I thought about was checking them both out at the same level, and using ".." in my Gradle config to get to the library from my app. This means that if I have a collaborator (and I may soon) they either need to tweak the config to suit them or check things out in the same way I did.

Or I could publish to a repo like mavenCentral or jcenter, but I'm still working on it, so that doesn't sound good either.

Is there a cleaner option that I'm missing?

Comment: Other solutions are to publish to your own (and possibly private) Bintray repo, use Git submodules, or to use a solution such as Prezi's [Pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple solution would be to publish your library with [JitPack](https://jitpack.io). You just would need to create a GitHub release and have a build file in your repository.

JitPack is a maven repository that pulls in packages from GitHub repositories. It checks out your code and builds it.

Comment: This is indeed the easiest solution, and you dont need to make a release at all. You can just use a snapshot build from master: with Tag = master-SNAPSHOT    
Also a release is the cleaner way of doing this

Answer (score 4):

Another option is [Gradle Source Dependencies](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies).
Basically you declare a dependency on a Git repository:

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository("https://github.com/gradle/native-samples-cpp-library.git") {
        producesModule("org.gradle.cpp-samples:utilities")
    }
}
```

and Gradle will clone and build that project.
Then you can add it as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.gradle.cpp-samples:utilities') {
        version {
            branch = 'release'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly as I write, Android Studio 3.4.1, still does not support sourceControl in gradle build files: modules are "red" in the code and "gradle sync" fails. If I build from the command line with ./gradlew build everything work.

Comment: @gabry any updates on whether this works now with AS 3.5.2 and Gradle6.0?